# Changing a space into a hyphen when having a code to come up with a phone number

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with one piece of my code.
I've got to get any space to return a hyphen (-).
As of right now, I've got a 0 returning in the space. 
Can anyone help me out with this problem.

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Project1 {
  public static int getNumber(char letter) {
    int ret = 0;

    if (letter== 'A' || letter=='a' || letter== 'B' || letter=='b' || letter=='C' || letter=='c') {
      return 2;
    }
    else if (letter== 'D' || letter=='d' || letter== 'E' || letter=='e' || letter=='F' || letter=='f') {
      return 3;
    }
    else if (letter== 'G' || letter=='g' || letter== 'H' || letter=='h' || letter=='I' || letter=='i') {
      return 4;
    }
    else if (letter== 'J' || letter=='j' || letter== 'K' || letter=='k' || letter=='L' || letter=='l') {
      return 5;
    }
    else if (letter== 'M' || letter=='m' || letter== 'N' || letter=='n' || letter=='O' || letter=='o') {
      return 6;
    }
    else if (letter== 'P' || letter=='p' || letter== 'Q' || letter=='q' || letter=='R' || letter=='r'|| letter=='S' || letter=='s') {
      return 7;
    }
    else if (letter== 'T' || letter=='t' || letter== 'U' || letter=='u' || letter=='V' || letter=='v') {
      return 8;
    }
    else if (letter== 'W' || letter=='w' || letter== 'X' || letter=='x' || letter=='Y' || letter=='y' || letter=='Z' || letter=='z') {
      return 9;
    }
    return ret;
  }



  public static void main (String[] arg) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a 7 letter phrase: ");
    String number = input.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      System.out.print(getNumber(number.toUpperCase().charAt(i)));
    }


  }
}
```

I also need to get the hyphen in the fourth spot. It should be xxx-xxxx. But if the phrase is xxxx xxx then it returns xxxx-xxx. Please someone help with this!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you initialize `ret` to be `0`, and there's no condition that contains a space. Therefore, you always end up with that initial value.

Add an additional condition:

```
}  else if(letter == ' ')  {
    return  '-';
}
```

Also, consider translating the [character to lowercase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29) with

```
letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
```

before checking it. That would allow you to eliminate half of your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's returning a 0 because "getNumber" is returning an Integer. So inside this integer function, you have a 'return ret' statement. which is Returning 0.

So now, make that "ret" a value that can not be a number in a phone. Let's say -2. So
     int ret = -2

Now in your client, handle receiving a "-2". So when you receive a "-2", print a "-" hyphen/ assume it's a hyphen. done.

Answer (score 0):

Add condition in getNumber()

```
if(letter==' ')
return '-';
```

You can change the return type as `char` that will be useful for this condition.

```
public static char getNumber(char letter) {
char ret = 0;

if (letter== 'A' || letter=='a' || letter== 'B' || letter=='b' || letter=='C' || letter=='c') {
  return '2';
}
else if (letter== 'D' || letter=='d' || letter== 'E' || letter=='e' || letter=='F' || letter=='f') {
  return '3';
}
else if (letter== 'G' || letter=='g' || letter== 'H' || letter=='h' || letter=='I' || letter=='i') {
  return '4';
}
else if (letter== 'J' || letter=='j' || letter== 'K' || letter=='k' || letter=='L' || letter=='l') {
  return '5';
}
else if (letter== 'M' || letter=='m' || letter== 'N' || letter=='n' || letter=='O' || letter=='o') {
  return '6';
}
else if (letter== 'P' || letter=='p' || letter== 'Q' || letter=='q' || letter=='R' || letter=='r'|| letter=='S' || letter=='s') {
  return '7';
}
else if (letter== 'T' || letter=='t' || letter== 'U' || letter=='u' || letter=='V' || letter=='v') {
  return '8';
}
else if (letter== 'W' || letter=='w' || letter== 'X' || letter=='x' || letter=='Y' || letter=='y' || letter=='Z' || letter=='z') {
  return '9';
}
else if(letter==' ')
return '-';
return ret;
```

}